# Styling element created in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an element in javascript with createElement.
And I want to style this element in css, not javascript.
I tried to give id in js and use that id in css but that didn't work.

Please help :(

Comment: hello and Welcome to SO.
If you want other users to help you it would be nice if you share what have you tried so far or make a snippet.
thanks

Comment: give a class and use a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `className` property. Like this:

```js
var elem = document.createElement("p");
elem.className = "text";
elem.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.";
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

```css
.text {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Check it in action on codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/BaQQZyY